# Filter elasticsearch by range of date on a string property

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

I need to query elasticsearch & filter the result to be in a range of dates.

the thing is the date property is mapped as a string.
is it possible to do so ?

this is the search query i'm using:

```
{
  "size": 1,
  "from": 0,

  "query": { 
    "bool": { 
      "must": [
        { "match": { "status":   "active"        }}, 
        { "match": { "last_action_state": "accepted" }}
      ],
      "filter": [ 
        {"missing" : { "field" : "store_id" }},
        { "range": { "list_time": { "gte": "2017/01/01 00:00:00", "lte": "2017/03/01 23:59:59", "format": "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"}}}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

the thing is i have no control over the mapping since it's created automatically by another program which index the documents, and i can't change the mapping once it's created.

**ps: elasticsearch version: 2.3**

**UPDATE:**

index info:

```
{
  "avindex_v3": {
    "aliases": {
      "avindex": {}
    },
    "mappings": {
      "ads": {
        "properties": {
          "account_id": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "ad_id": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "ad_params": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "body": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "category": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "city": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "company_ad": {
            "type": "boolean"
          },
          "email": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "images": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "lang": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "last_action_state": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "list_date": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "list_id": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "list_time": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "modified_at": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "modified_ts": {
            "type": "double"
          },
          "name": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "orig_date": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "orig_list_time": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "phone": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "phone_hidden": {
            "type": "boolean"
          },
          "price": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "region": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "status": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "store_id": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "subject": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "type": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "user_id": {
            "type": "long"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "settings": {
      "index": {
        "creation_date": "1493216710928",
        "number_of_shards": "5",
        "number_of_replicas": "1",
        "uuid": "WEHGLF8iRyGk3Xgbmo7H8Q",
        "version": {
          "created": "2040499"
        }
      }
    },
    "warmers": {}
  }
}
```

Comment: You'll need to figure out a way to modify that mapping and change the field to a `date` instead of `string` otherwise range queries on string dates will not work as you discovered. One way could be to define an [index template](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html) that contains the proper field mapping, so that the index is created with the proper field types and you don't need to rely on that other program.

Comment: Thanx @Val , i didn't know about the index templates, if you could post your comment as a response the i could accept it as a correct response.

Comment: Can you provide some more info on how your index is named? and also the current mapping you have? simply run `curl -XGET localhost:9200/index_name` and update your question with the results

Comment: i added the index informations in the post @Val

Comment: i also created the template, but when reindexing, the template didn't apply

Answer (score 1):

You can try to give it as a keyword like this :

```
{
    "range": {
        "list_time.keyword": {
            "gte": "2020-08-12 22:24:55.56",
            "lte": "2020-08-12 22:24:56.56"
        }
    }
}
```